# TikZ-UML classes with same name but different node names

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-uml

I'm using TikZ-UML to draw a class diagram with multiple packages, and classes with the same name but located in different packages. The thing is, I want to put relations on those classes, but I can't reference one in particular because they have the same name.

I already tried using the `name` option of the `\umlclass` macro to change the node name, but I can't seem to be able to reference the node name from the `\umlrelation` arguments. Here is a minimal (non-)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \umlsimpleclass[name=a]{A}
        \umlsimpleclass[x=2, name=b]{A}
        \umlassoc{a}{b}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `alias` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \umlsimpleclass[alias=a]{A}
        \umlsimpleclass[x=2, alias=b]{B}
        \umlassoc{a}{b}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, had been stuck on this for 2 hours :-)